# How can I prevent postfix from resending messages from its mailq when restoring from backup (can I delete them before restart?)

Tags: postfix

I'm running a small application server (raspberry pi) with a `btrfs subvolume`  as its root filessystem.  This server has a simple `postfix` running to catch mails sent by the application and deliver them to the main server.  This is so, if for any reason the main mail server is down or unreachable, application generated e-mails are not lost. These mails are to clients of the business.

The application itself runs in a separate `btrfs subvolume`, as is `/var/log`.  I say this because I use the `btrfs subvolume snapshot` on a regular basis to take a backup of the running root filesystem.  This is `tar'ed` to another machine for safe keeping. As the main changes to the rootfs occur infrequently I currently do this weekly, but might drop back to only doing it monthly.

I maintain this application server remotely for a small business.

The most likely failure of this raspberry pi is the sd card corrupts.  I had this happen to me on a raspberry pi on my home which acts as the main mail server for the home and despite having backups of every thing it still took me several days to restore properly. For this reason I am rethinking how to recover from such a failure on this application server with the minimal of down time.

I am confident that should this server fail, that the office manager can take a spare pre-prepared sd card and replace the failed one. This would be sufficient for me to `ssh` into it, with a small "dummy" filesystem as the root, while I untar the final rootfs, update the `/boot/cmdline.txt` to boot into this new root (I get disconnected and have to reconnect obviously at this point).

The only issue is that potentially, when the original tar backup was made, that the postfix mailq was non empty.  I don't want the final reboot stage for postfix to startup notice that its queue is not empty and potentially send e-mails from a backup that could be a week (or even a month) old.

In all the discussion about this questioners are told to use `postsuper -d ALL`, but by the time I can do that on a running system its too late, queued mails could well have already been sent!  I am thinking maybe I could `chroot` into the new root and run `postsuper` from there before the reboot, but by the far the easiest would just be to delete the files; but I don't know which ones!

What is the best way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and tried and tested it and it appears to have worked.

Essentially there are a range directories within `/var/spool/postfix` that store the messages.  Delete all the files in these and it in essence empties all the queues.  With the root filesystem mounted at `_root` (way before it is loaded into the raspberry pi), the code I use to do this is

```
_root/var/spool/postfix/{defer,bounce,maildrop,incoming,active,deferred,hold,flush} -type f -exec rm {} \;
```